# Getting a hash from map instead of an array

Tags: ruby

```
a = ["ab", "dc", "vv", "dd"]
a.each_with_index.map { |v, i| { ("prefix_" + i.to_s).to_sym => v }}
 => [{:prefix_0=>"ab"}, {:prefix_1=>"dc"}, {:prefix_2=>"vv"}, {:prefix_3=>"dd"}]
```

I want to get a hash as a return value. How can I do this?

Comment: It is not clear what hash you want.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Don't be *Rude*... Your *question* was not clear really. I took a *wild* guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way :

```
a = ["ab", "dc", "vv", "dd"]
Hash[a.map.with_index { |v, i| ["prefix_#{i}".to_sym, v] }]
# => {:prefix_0=>"ab", :prefix_1=>"dc", :prefix_2=>"vv", :prefix_3=>"dd"}
```

In Ruby 2.1 >=, use [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h) as below :-

```
a.map.with_index { |v, i| ["prefix_#{i}".to_sym, v] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain enumerators together, so another option is something like this:

```
 a.each_with_index.each_with_object({}) { |(v, i), h| h["prefix_#{i}"] = v }
```